# PowerBI - Column output based on another column value and time function

Tags: switch-statement, powerbi, calculated-columns, powerbi-desktop

I have a table like that:

[image]

I'm comparing values from CurrentMonth vs PreviousMonth (based on the month selected in the slicer) for all of the KPIs, and based on that, I assign a specific result.

However, for each KPI, there is a logic behind when comparing. The logic is:

[image]

So, for KPI A, the CurrentMonth value must be 10% higher then PreviousMonth. When this is true, then assign 1. If not true, then 0. For KPI B, it has to be 3% higher. And for KPI C, it just needs to be higher.

To pull the CurrentMonth and PreviousMonth values, I created two measures, one of them with a time function:

```
CurrentMonth = SUM( [KPIValue] )
```

and

```
PreviousMonth = CALCULATE (
SUM( [KPIValue] );
PREVIOUSMONTH( [Date] )
)
```

I tried to create a Column in my table to assign the output (Result), and used a Switch function like this:

```
Result = SWITCH (
[KPIName];
"KPI A"; IF( [CurrentMonth] >= [PreviousMonth]*1.10;1;0 );
"KPI B"; IF( [CurrentMonth] >= [PreviousMonth]*1.03;1;0 );
"KPI C"; IF( [CurrentMonth] >= [PreviousMonth];1;0 );
)
```

My issue is that when I try to use this *Switch*, it does not work since the PreviousMonth comes as blank (it can not calculate a time function for each row of the table - only works as a measure).

I'm now lost how should I proceed from here. I tried to create a *Measure* instead of a *Column*, but then the Switch function does not accept the KPIName as a parameter.

Any ideas? Hope I've been clear here, if not, let me know what further information you need.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. As a Measure (not column), include *SELECTEDVALUE* to be able to retrieve KPIName.

```
Result = SWITCH (
SELECTEDVALUE([KPIName]);
"KPI A"; IF( [CurrentMonth] >= [PreviousMonth]*1.10;1;0 );
"KPI B"; IF( [CurrentMonth] >= [PreviousMonth]*1.03;1;0 );
"KPI C"; IF( [CurrentMonth] >= [PreviousMonth];1;0 );
)
```